# «Старый рыдван» — тавтология?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, словосочетания, тавтология

*Она молча, сосредоточенно лавировала среди возрастающих потоков утреннего транспорта, и Страйк отметил, как ему нравится ее смех. Признал он и кое-что другое: ему куда приятней было сидеть с Робин в этом **старом рыдване** и трепаться о всякой ерунде, чем ужинать с Элин.*
[Р. Гэлбрейт. На службе зла](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=53624&p=48) (перевод с английского Е. Петровой)

Хотелось бы понять: является ли словосочетание *старый рыдван* тавтологичным?

Answer (score 3):

В смысле плеоназмом? Мне кажется, нет.

Значение слова **рыдван** по словарю Ушакова:

РЫДВАН, рыдвана, м. Большая дорожная карета (старин.). С поклажей и с семьей дворян четверкою рыдван тащился. Крылов. || Неуклюжий, громоздкий, старомодный экипаж (шутл.).

Старомодный не означает "старый". Он может быть и новым, только купленным, но всё равно громоздким.

Comment: Дело в том, что этой словарной формулировке более 70 лет, а книга современная. Вот что у Ефремовой (гораздо позднее): _2. Cтapaя гpoмoздкaя пoвoзкa, дpaндyлeт_ (paзг. пpeнeбp.). https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/210926/РЫДВАН

Comment: Ну, это уже личное восприятие Ефремовой, а молодой лингвист добавит своё восприятие - уродливый. Это же не будет объективным определением, первоначальное определение более точное. Мы же с Вами не знаем, каким словарём пользовался автор перевода, вполне возможно, что старым.